# Does Get-AzureRmHdInsightJobOutput return an object?

Tags: azure, pentaho, azure-hdinsight, azure-powershell

I am currently working on a pre-existing kettle job that calls a powershell script that sends Azure HdInsight a pig job. Get-AzureHdInsightJobOutput is part of this script and is now deprecated. So I am replacing it with Get-AzureRmHdInsightJobOutput. However the new cmdlet has two parameter sets, one for display and one for download. I need an object to be returned in order to avoid making changes to the kettle job.

I'm hoping to find out if the display parameters will return an object or if they just print out the results.

Comment: Hi, does the answer provided helpful to your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Your answer is helpful, but I won't know if it is the right answer answer until I test the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, `Get-AzureRmHdInsightJobOutput` cmdlet will return **string object** when in use with the **Display** parameter set, regardless of the DisplayOutputType.

You can refer to the source code of this cmdlet below in the Azure PowerShell github link:

[GetAzureHDInsightJobOutputCommand.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ResourceManager/HDInsight/Commands.HDInsight/JobCommands/GetAzureHDInsightJobOutputCommand.cs)

Hope this helps!